# GreenPlum DATE_PART function convert into Hive SQL

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, greenplum

I am migrating Greenplum to HiveSql but i could not able to find any such below kind of solution in google search. please help me.

```
DATE_PART('minute',ck_2::time - ck_1::time) gap_1_2
```

please help me , how do we convert above the statement to hivesql.

Comment: What is sample input and expected out put  as every one will not know green pump function doing.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong ask here is time difference in minute for hive,

it can be achieved using  unix_timestamp it covert time in second and then devide it by 60 and get time difference in  minute

ie -

```
 SELECT (( unix_timestamp(ck_2) - unix_timestamp(ck_1))/60 ) as gap_1_2
```

Comment: please help me one more conversion : replace(id_number,'','','''')::character varying(100) id_number

Comment: i tried select cast(replace('12345','','','''') as string) id_number but not working

Comment: It will be great if you read some basic hiveql . replace is not there is translate or regexp_replace  https://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-replace-function-and-examples.html/